# Android : SQLITE Select Query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have one table of `student_fee` where columns are :

- `id_fee`
- `id_student`
- `student_name`
- `fee_month`

Here i am inserting data based on students with their monthly tuition fee payment.
From this easily i can query which students paid their monthly fees, suppose January fee by Query Like : `Select * From student_fee Where fee_month = "January";`

But how can i search which students not paid their monthly fee only in January?

Comment: `Select from student_fee where fee_month != "January" ` Like this ?

Comment: what about `NOT EXISTS` do you know sql basics?

Comment: @Greggz "!=" gives same result like "=".

Comment: @Selvin tried **NOT EXISTS** still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normaly you should have normalized database tables to avoid storing the student name over and over and over again:

```
<!-- sql -->
CREATE TABLE students    ( id  INTEGER,  name  varchar(60));

INSERT INTO students    ( id ,  name ) VALUES    (1, 'stud_1');
INSERT INTO students    ( id ,  name ) VALUES    (2, 'stud_2');
INSERT INTO students    ( id ,  name ) VALUES    (3, 'stud_3');
INSERT INTO students    ( id ,  name ) VALUES    (4, 'stud_4');
INSERT INTO students    ( id ,  name ) VALUES    (5, 'stud_5');

CREATE TABLE student_fee  (id INTEGER, studentId INTEGER, month varchar(20));

INSERT INTO student_fee    (id ,  studentId ,  month ) VALUES    (1, 1, 'january');
INSERT INTO student_fee    (id ,  studentId ,  month ) VALUES    (2, 2, 'january'); 
INSERT INTO student_fee    (id ,  studentId ,  month ) VALUES    (4, 2, 'february');
INSERT INTO student_fee    (id ,  studentId ,  month ) VALUES    (5, 3, 'february');
INSERT INTO student_fee    (id ,  studentId ,  month ) VALUES    (6, 4, 'february');
```

And you would query it like so:

```
select * 
from  students  
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from student_fee
    where students.id = studentid 
    and month = 'january')
```

Output:

```
id  name
3   stud_3
4   stud_4
5   stud_5
```

(Sql Syntax is mysql, not sure about sqlite)